# different reaction between with UI and REST API

Tags: acumatica

I would like to update the description field with the order number. It's ok when I use the ui acumatica, but the field is empty when I use the rest webservice.

Endpoint : Salesorder?

```
protected void SOOrder_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  BAccount un_client=PXSelect<BAccount , Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.CustomerID);
  if (un_client!=null)
  {
    row.OrderDesc=Mid(Convert.ToString(row.OrderNbr)+" (" +Convert.ToString(row.CustomerOrderNbr)+") "+Convert.ToString(un_client.AcctName),0,250);
  }     
}
```

Update 2024-03-02
When I use the SOOrder_RowPersisting

```
protected void SOOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  BAccount un_client=PXSelect<BAccount , Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.CustomerID);
  if (un_client!=null)
  {
    row.OrderDesc=Mid(Convert.ToString(row.OrderNbr)+" (" +Convert.ToString(row.CustomerOrderNbr)+") "+Convert.ToString(un_client.AcctName),0,250);
  }         
}
```

I have not the good OrderNbr, because I have not save
[image]

And, when I save the new is not update
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RowPersisting` instead of `RowPersisted`, and you also need to send some real data update with your request. It's OK if you send some placeholder data in the Description.

```
{
    "OrderType": {
        "value": "SO"
    },
    "OrderNbr": {
        "value": "SO006777"
    },
    "Description": {
        "value": "it will be updated when persisting the row"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, but when I use the rowpersisting, the OrderNbr field is not avaible (I update the question).

Comment: If you do it in RowPersisted, then Description will be changed, but not saved. You might need to do this update with a separate call, after the record was inserted.